# Django how to import value in request function to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following project structure:

```
_stato_patrimoniale
___views.py

_iva
___utility.py
```

In the stato patrimoniale I have the following code:

```
from iva.utility import my_func 

def stato_patrimoniale(request):
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    last_account_year=float(now.year)-1 #definizione dell'ultimo anno contabile
    now = now.year
    if request.method == 'POST':
        year = request.POST['year']
        if year != '':
            now = year
            last_account_year = float(now) - 1

    data=my_func()
    iva_a_credito=data['iva_a_credito']
```

Now in my `iva.utility` I have the following code:

```
def my_func():
  pass
```

Now I want to import in `my_func()`the value of `last_account_year` from the `stato_patrimoniale`. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the value through as a parameter

views.py:

```
from iva.utility import my_func

def stato_patrimoniale(request):
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    last_account_year=float(now.year)-1 #definizione dell'ultimo anno contabile
    now = now.year
    if request.method == 'POST':
        year = request.POST['year']
        if year != '':
            now = year
            last_account_year = float(now) - 1

    data=my_func(last_account_year)
    iva_a_credito=data['iva_a_credito']
```

other file:

```
def my_func(last_account_year)
    // do something with last_account_year
```